# Instance method nearly matches optional requirement of protocol (but is not a near match)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following warning in Xcode 8: `Instance method 'didSelectSearchResult' nearly matches optional requirement 'didPresentSearchController' of protocol 'UISearchControllerDelegate'`
I do know that there are lots of "nearly matches" warnings in Xcode, but in this case it is not a near match. Is it really necessary for me to rename my own protocol to something else because Xcode has a terrible interpretation of what "nearly matches" mean?

The protocol is made by me and defined as:

```
protocol CountrySearchDelegate: class {
    func didSelectSearchResult(_ result: CountrySearchCV.SearchResult)
}
```

This has noting to do with UISearchControllerDelegate and I really don't want to rename code just because Xcode throws out random warnings. Anyone else encountered this?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but that does seem maddening!

Comment: Does the warning appear at the protocol definition or at the implementation of that method? Can you provide a *self-contained* code example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The warning appears in the implementation of the method. There are no warnings in the protocol declaration. I'll see if I can make a small Xcode project, but since the argument in the function is CountrySearchCV.SearchResult it might require a bit of code to declare this custom type as well.